# ASP 4.5 GridView Template Field with possible null object

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, webforms

I have a list of objects in my GridView where the child object could be null.  I can't seem to get the right syntax to test for null and ignore/print empty string.

I see 3 possible answers for this:

1. This can be done easily in the aspx file in a declarative way
2. I have to do it in code behind
3. it can't be done like this and I need to sort out my list method and project a new one with no nulls, something like that.

Here is the grid view code, `GetMyData` is a method that just returns `IEnumerable<MyClass>` and this comes from EntityFramework where I'm using the `Include` method to eager load the Customer object.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server"
    CssClass="listTable"
    ItemType="MyClass"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    SelectMethod="GetMyData"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="listAlternate">
    <Columns>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="ReferenceDate" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# (Item.Customer != null) ? Item.Customer .Name : ""; %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>       
</asp:GridView>
```

Please note, I'm using entity framework 6.1 and .Net 4.5 in this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `;`

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("Item.Customer") != null ? Eval("Item.Customer.Name) : "" %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: yeah, that's the solution, what an embarrassing mistake. Thanks.